# ColdFusion 9 ORM - Not Configured For The Current Application

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a directory watcher event gateway instance that is responsible for parsing, loading and storing data received in the CSV format via SFTP. Using `entityNew` and `entityLoad`, this process iteratively constructs and flushes a transactional ORM session, ultimately inserting new and updating existing database records reflecting the received data.

This process sporadically fails and reports the following exception:

```
coldfusion.orm.ORMUtils$ORMNotConfiguredException: ORM is not configured for the
current application. at coldfusion.orm.ORMUtils.getPersistenceManager(ORMUtils.java:55)
at coldfusion.orm.ORMUtils._executeQuery(ORMUtils.java:332)
```

**Note:** The above exception has been severely abbreviated, but hopefully includes enough detail to serve its purpose.

This exception is not caught and reported by the enterprise server monitor, however it is reflected in the exception log. Because of this I am unable to utilize the enterprise server monitor to review the failure in full detail. I experience between 1 and 3 failures on a daily basis with no correlating patterns in regards to the time of day, file size, application / database server resource consumption or received data transmission source.

I have verified with a case-insensitive directory recursive search that the `ormEnabled` and `ormSettings.datasource` properties only exist in the root-level `Application.cfc` component and are hard-coded. I have also verified with the same type of search that I do not have any rogue `ormReload` method invocations existing in the codeset.

Accepting answers and welcoming theories now! :)

**I'd like to extend a very special thanks for every logical contribution!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that, since you are using an event gateway, that the application is not loaded when the page is hit.  Without the application being loaded, CF cannot determine that ORM is enabled.  It's also possible that the it works a good deal of the time, because the application was already running.  How's that for theory?

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the feedback. I am writing an application log upon invocation of the `Application.cfc' component `onApplicationStart` method, and can ensure that the application is not restarting, and is in a ready state.